# Getting value from response.body in ruby from XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, xml-parsing

My response.body from a XML get looks like this:

```
<ns1:Expire>0320</ns1:Expire>
  <ns1:Track1Data i:nil="true"/>
   <ns1:EcommerceSecurityData i:nil="true"/>
     <ns8:Amount >10.00</ns8:Amount>
```

How can get the valueo of "Amount" as a variable?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Are you using Nokogiri?